# Memory efficient way of using an NSTimer to update a MenuBar Mac application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, launchd

I am creating an application for Mac, in Objective C, which will run in the Menu-bar and do periodic Desktop operations (such as changing the wallpaper). I am creating the application so that it stays in the Menu bar at all times, allowing easy access to configuration options and other information. My main concern is how to schedule my app to run every X minutes to do the desktop operations.

The most common solution I have seen is using NSTimer, however, I am concerned that it will not be memory efficient (after reading the following page on [Apple Developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/MinimizeTimerUse.html). Using an NSTimer will prevent the laptop from going to sleep, and will need an always-running thread to check for when the NSTimer has elapsed. Is there a more memory-efficient way of using NSTimer to schedule these operations?

Alternately, is there a way to use LaunchD to initiate a call to my application (which is in the Menu bar) so that it can handle the event and do the desktop operations. I think that the second way is better, but am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Do you mean energy efficient?

Answer (score 0):

First, excellent instincts on keeping this low-impact. But you're probably over-worried in this particular case.

When they say "waking the system from an idle state" they don't mean system-level "sleep" where the screen goes black. They mean idle state. The CPU can take little mini-naps for fractions of a second when there isn't work that immediately needs to be done. This can dramatically reduce power requirements, even while the system is technically "awake."

The problem with having lots of timers flying around isn't so much their frequencies as their tolerances. Say one you have 10 timers with a 1 second frequency, but they're offset from each other by 100ms (just by chance of what time it was when they happened to start). That means the longest possible "gap" is 100ms. But if they were configured at 1 second with a 0.9 second tolerance (i.e. between 1s and 1.9s), then the system could schedule them all together, do a bunch of work, and spend most of the second idle. That's much better for power.

To be a good timer citizen, you should first set your timer at the interval you really want to do work. If it is common for your timer to fire, but all you do is check some condition and reschedule the timer, then you're wasting power. (Sounds like you already have this in hand.) And the second thing you should do is set a reasonable tolerance. The default is 0 which is a very small tolerance (it's not actually "0 tolerance," but it's very small compared to a minutes). For your kind of problem, I'd probably use a tolerance of at least 1s.

I highly recommend the [Energy Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/712/) talk from WWDC 2013. You may also be interested in the later [Writing Energy Efficient Code](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/710/) sessions from 2014 and [Achieving All-day Battery Life](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/707/) from 2015.

It is possible of course to do with with launchd, but it adds a lot of complexity, especially on installation. I don't recommend it for the problem you're describing.